# Add padding between "Still have a question about X?

Tags: discussion, documentation, design

In documentation the footer of a topic / example / whatever the heck its called has an "Ask Question" button.  Please add padding-top to this button:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh! But... but... this looks as if it would be NSFW...

Comment: Btw, the thing this button is located at the end of is called a "topic".

Comment: We can thank @honk, we finally can't unseen it!

Comment: Next time don't honk that horn please. This post is already horny.

Comment: _\*diabolical laughter\*_

Comment: Is that an Ask Question in your pocket or are you just happy to see me?

Comment: I read "Jon" written sideways at the right of the handmade circle. Jon Skeet, I guess. Is he NSFW? Edit: Ah, the OP is also called Jon.

Comment: I recommend margin instead of padding - I guess that's what you meant too.